# Select only uppercase sentence

Tags: regex, uppercase, sentence

It is really silly, but I'm unable to extract sentences which are with UPPERCASE letters.

**This is an example of my text:**

```
NÁLADA.
Na všech stromech visí stíny.
Vítr žaluje v trávě
To je štěstí mého srdce.
NOVÉ JARO A MY.
Tančí víly při měsíci v smaragdových zahradách, skvosty v kšticích, úsměv v líci tančí v světle, tančí v tmách.
PRÁCE
které spaly staletí, tančí atlasové víly v nyvém sadě zakletí.
RESIGNACE.
skvosty v kšticích, úsměv
```

**If would like to capture:**

```
NÁLADA.
NOVÉ JARO A MY.
PRACE
RESIGNACE.
```

**I tried several regexes, but there is always some problem:**

```
[\w\s]+
[[A-Ž]+\s]+
```

Comment: Try `^[^\n\p{Ll}]*\p{Lu}[^\n\p{Ll}]*$` / `^\P{Ll}*\p{Lu}\P{Ll}*$`

Comment: I'm using sublime reader, and this regex is throwing regex syntax error.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Isn't the slash (/) a syntax error? Should be OR (|) ?

Comment: Does it works for you with my example text? For me it throwing regex syntax error even with |

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dpI2tK/1

Comment: Still error from sublime reader:

`Line 15573, Column 1; Escape sequence was neither a valid property nor a valid character class name. The error occurred while parsing the regular expression fragment: 'I}]*\p{Lu}>>>HERE>>>[A\n\p{LI}'. in regular expression A[A\n\p{LI...`



How can valid regex be invalid in other software?.... this regex "standards" are madness.

Comment: It's even worse for sublime reader. It has its own proprietary custom regex engine that isn't open-source.

Comment: Are you familiar with Atom editor? What about this one

Comment: Try `[^\n[:lower:]]*[[:upper:]][^\n[:lower:]]*$`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your regex engine (Sublime) supports POSIX named classes, you could use

```
^[^[:lower:]]+$
```

This simply looks for a line that has 1 or characters so long as none are lowercase letters.

(Further [explanation at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dpI2tK/2))

You asked for "sentences" rather than lines. That's a little more effort:

```
(?<=^|[.?!]\s)[^[:lower:].?!]+(?:[.?!]|$)
```

This seeks the end of a sentence (meaning sentence-terminating characters like period, question mark, and exclamation point can't be matched until the end, thus the longer negated character class). In addition to matching anchors at the start and end of a line, this accepts previous text that ended a sentence and the end of a sentence. This is done by seeking proper punctuation. Look-behinds must be fixed width, so I'm assuming a single space after punctuation (if there are additional spaces following the period/question/exclamation, they'll merely be a part of the match).

If you have sentence-ending punctuation inside a sentence (like "BUY AT EXAMPLE.COM (PLEASE!) IF YOU LIKE THIS.") then this will miss that (it'll match "BUY AT EXAMPLE." and "IF YOU LIKE THIS." but it'll miss the rest). There are complicated ways around that using lookaheads, but I have no idea if they (or any of this, actually) will work in Sublime's regex engine.

(Further [explanation at Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/dpI2tK/3))